# Why PayPal Rest API use namespaces?

Tags: rest, paypal

Ive been reading PayPal REST API documentation, which is very well documented and helpful for beginners like me, I want to understand why does PayPal REST API use namespaces for resource collection?

1. Do they have common resources, due to which they use namespaces for differentiation?
2. They want to make it look logical by grouping resources into namespaces?
3. other reasons?

I really like the idea of how PayPal have documented their REST APIs and want to know more about it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You definitely mentioned a lot of the right reasons. Namespaces are a good way to express the structure of the api by grouping together resources that fit under common umbrellas. If you look at the API specs, there are common objects that are shared within namespaces, which has to do with individual requirements of a namespace and what should be exposed.

One reason I would add would be that well designed namespaces could help future proof your API design e.g. if you see exposing more resources under a namespace in the future, it makes sense to have one, even though currently there is only one resource that is under that namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I gave a talk explaining some of the aspects of managing our API portfolio at Nordic APIs a few months ago. You can check out the video, I think it might explain some of the concepts for you (although @avi-das 's answer was certainly adequate).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QCDH0ePRF08